# URLs to user page is broken

Tags: comments, author, theme-twenty-thirteen

My domain is http://mongage.com
I don't know what happened to my site. the user URL linking to author/user page is broken. I switched to a new theme, but no success.

I am using thentythirteen and the following code:

```
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) ); ?>" rel="author">
```

in my functions.php, I am rewriting the user/author page URL with the following code:

```
function change_author_permalinks() {
global $wp_rewrite;
$wp_rewrite->author_base = 'membres';
$wp_rewrite->author_structure = '/' . $wp_rewrite->author_base. '/%author%/';
}
 add_action('init','change_author_permalinks');
```

but when I mouse over an author/user name I get "http://domain.com/members//"
where it simply get cut off before the author/user name. I manually type the rest in the URL, but get a 404
deleting the custom author/user URL or switching to a new theme did not fix it either.

would appreciate if anyone can put me in the right direction.
Actually I started from scratch twice no success. It was perfectly working fine before.
By the way, I have customize the comments system to work as a petition signup allowing only 1 comment/signup per user. I have also moved my comment form to the sidebar.

Comment: Is `membres` a typo in your code or your question?

Comment: Sorry mixing up french and english, but that aspect is correct in the coding and the spelling is not the issue.